# UIButton apperance change disclosure too why? how to avoid it?

Tags: ios, uiappearance, appearance, customizing

So when I customize my button I put a background image like this:

```
- (void) styleUIButtons {
    UIImage *buttonNormalBg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_normal" ] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *buttonSelectedBgb = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_selected" ] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];

    id appereance = [UIButton appearance];

    [appereance setTintColor:self.mainNavigationBarTextColor];
    [appereance setBackgroundImage:buttonNormalBg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [appereance setBackgroundImage:buttonSelectedBgb forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

But the disclosure indicator of the table change horribly to a single line. Why does this happened? and how can I avoid it? Am I customizing the button wrongly?[image]

Answer (score 0):

`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-AppendixA).

Use [`resizableImageWithCapInsets:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a) instead.

Comment: change themethod but I don't see how that can mess up with the disclosure indicator

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and the images are working fine for me.
The only thing I had to add was a frame.

The tintColor only seems to work when there aren't background images.